# DataGridView databinding to List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to bind the itemssource property of my datagridview to a list of objects whose property names I will not know until runtime.

The code currently compiles but nothing shows up in the columns (the datagrid shows a row for each item in my list, but nothing in each column)

setting up column bindings

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in _columns)
{
    Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn textCol = new Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
    textCol.Header = pair.Key;
    textCol.Binding = new Binding(pair.Value);
    ItemListDataGrid.Columns.Add(textCol);
}
```

example hard-coded List:

```
List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>> itemSet = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> item1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
item1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("ACTION","ACTION"));
itemSet.Add(item1);
ItemListDataGrid.ItemsSource = itemSet;
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: You're not giving us anything to go on. What does "I cannot get it to work" mean? It throws an exception? Show us the exception. Show us the code.

Comment: the column shows up blank in the datagridview, as stated above. edit: added code for more clarity

Comment: Why not a `List<Dictionary<K,V>>`?

Comment: I want to bind the itemssource to a enumerable set of objects where I don't know the keys until runtime. Each "row" has multiple "columns".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a DataTable that is populated dynamically, I was able to solve this problem relatively quickly. The expando object would also work, but I only need to load the objects into a datagridview for selection, and have no need of them after that point. Because of this, I decided not to go with the expando object in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is implement an expando object:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Feb/08/Creating-a-dynamic-extensible-C-Expando-Object

That said more info on what you are looking for would help answer your question.

Comment: I need some way of representing an object that can be used as an Itemssource for the DataGridView without knowing ahead of time what the  property names are, or how many of them there are.

Comment: Yup - it is called an expando object and the link shows you how to do that using a dynamic.

Comment: While the expando object does solve my problem, I think that it would be more complicated than what I need for this specific problem.